# Understanding dual spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

My professor asked me to give him an example about dual spaces from our real life so I was thinking if we take the set of all our actions as the space X can the space of all our thoughts be the dual space  ?!!

It is clear that the set of actions is a vector space : 
     Adding two action give an action and multiplying an action by a scalar give an action ( the addition means doing more than one action and multiplication by a scalar means increase or decrease the power of the action).
        The norm of this space is the time we need to do an action. So if time separating a sequence of actions is very small we say that this sequence converges
        The reason I thing that the dual of this space should be the space of thought is that thoughts and actions are connected to each other and if we have a convergente sequence of actions we surely have a convergente sequence of thoughts but the inverse isn't true we can have a convergente sequence of thought without actions.

```
 What do you think about this example, should I explain it to my professor ??????
```

Comment: When I think of real life analogies, I always think of friendship as not an equivalence relation. (If Bob if a friend of Joe and Joe is a friend of Jennifer, Bob is not necessarily a friend of Jennifer.)

I think you should aim to have an example as concrete and convincing as something like that.

Comment: I see ok I'll try to think about it

Answer (score 0):

A possible example is the following. We have a shop with a (finite) set of articles $S$. Let $V$ be the vector space of prices for the objects in $S$, then a choice of things to buy would give you an element of the dual space $V^*$ (seen as a functional giving you back how much do you spend depending on the price tags).

Comment: the dual space of V is the space of all continuous functional defined on V. Your choice of functional is good, but your dual is not sweatable. ( I noticed that your field of work is algebra, so I tink we have different definition of the meaning of dual spaces)

Comment: @nour In the finite-dimensional case (such as in my example) the algebraic dual and the continuous dual coincide. I'm sure our definitions of dual space perfectly agree in this case.

Comment: In this case, I don't think your exemple is true, because firstly you disregard the linearity secondly I don't see the relation between the dual you chosen and the functional

Comment: @nour Then you clearly haven't understood my example, nor are you making any effort to understand anything I have told you.

Comment: I think you are being offensive more than being helpful, I spent hours trying understanding you but every time I got more confused for this reason I won't reply you anymore

Answer (score -1):

A concrete example is the force applying on an object. The newton second law of motion said that Force = mass x acceleration. It is clear that here the mathematical representation of force is functional that map the set of masses to a real number. Then, if we take the set of masses as a space X. Then it dual would be the set of forces.

Comment: you could at least explain you idea, why it is wrong?

Comment: For starters, the space of possible masses is $1$-dimensional and the space of forces is $3$-dimensional.

Comment: The newton second law of motion said that Force = mass x acceleration, so how could the force be of 3 dimension and the mass of 1 dimension?

Comment: Acceleration is a vector, not a scalar. Momentum, on the other side, is an element of the dual space to the space of velocity. But if you're just learning linear algebra, I doubt you had any advanced courses in classical mechanics yet.

Comment: I think you should know that the acceleration is not always a vector it could be a scalar when the direction is not important (like the speed) and clearly in my example I meant the scalar version of acceleration.

Comment: The fact that acceleration can be identified with a scalar sometimes is somewhat of an abuse. Anyway, your example **is** wrong. I'm sure you can come up with something better.

Comment: No, that is also extremely wrong. But as you don't seem to be listening to me, I will not answer to your comments anymore.

Comment: Didn't you say "is an element of the dual space to the space of velocity"

Comment: Momentum is, not acceleration. I posted a better example. Try to come up with other ones, too. It will be a good exercise for you.

Comment: to correct it I have to take the momentum as a fonctional, so if V is the space of velocity then its dual would be the space of momentum (what about this)